# Failure of Palais-Smale Condition C and the Mini-Max Principle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations, critical-point-theory

To get a thorough analysis of the critical point structure of a smooth function $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$ on a smooth Hilbert manifold $M$, a compactness assumption gets us far. That assumption is *Condition C* of Palais and Smale (note that this is automatically satisfied for $M$ compact). It ultimately implies (for instance) the *Deformation Lemma* and the *Mini-Max Principle*.

But what if Condition C fails? I'm interested in to what extent I lose control over the function. For instance, I am aware of Uhlenbeck's "perturbation method", where if $f$ doesn't satisfy Condition C then we can look at $f_\varepsilon=f+\varepsilon\cdot g$ (fix function $g$) that satisfies Condition C and try to get critical points of $f$ as limits of those of $f_\varepsilon$.
**When Condition C fails, is there a work-around to save the Mini-Max Principle?**

Comment: I don't think you'll get far unless you're at the borderline where Condition C (and compactness) just barely fails. If so, Uhlenbeck and others have shown in certain particular situations (minimal hypersurfaces and self-dual Yang-Mills connections are the most notable examples), there is a global minimum but it lives outside the original Hilbert manifold you started with. I have no idea what could happen at a saddle point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some works on this, but maybe THE expert on this topic is Abbas Bahri. Take a look at his works or google "critical point at infinity".

See, for example: [this paper](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0100779) or his book ""Critical Points at Infinity in Some Variational Problem".

Comment: I see this is a way to get back the deformation lemma, in particular for studying the flow of a functional. Does this also help us with the critical point structure of the function itself?

Comment: I think you must make your question more precise: are you trying to find some general condition that will allow you to generalize Palis-Smale (unlikely) or do you have a concrete problem in mind and are wondering what sort of technique or trick will allow you to work around it ?

Comment: I think what alvarezpaiva is trying to say is that it's impossible to say much unless you describe a rather specific concrete situation in which you are trying to use the minimax principle.